# Custom error page: The path is either invalid or you do not have access to it

Tags: 7, uri

I'm trying to add a custom page, by using `admin/config/system/site-information`

When I enter the field, as follows:

**Default 404 (not found) page**

```
http://mysite.com/errors/404.html
```

It shows the following error:

`The path 'errors/404.html' is either invalid or you do not have access to it.`

Though when I enter in my browser: `http://mysite.com/errors/404.html` it opens just fine.

So, what's wrong with `Drupal`, why it doesn't see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to `admin/config/system/site-information` to enter the path in the field **Default 404 (not found) page**, you don't have to add `.html` just write `errors/404` and it will work.

Comment: well, it's the same, guess it only handles the very pages created in drupal itself

Comment: When you said _custom page_, how did you create this page? (Did you use a content type like `basic page` or anything else? If you want to use a path in drupal, he has to know it before)

Comment: Well it was just one html page I wanted to display. Now I understand, I had to add it, so I `block` instead. And I want only to display this block, I tried `block/4` but it doesn't work either. Is there any way to assign a node for a block?

Comment: You can't assign a block in a path (i think, i'm not a Drupal expert) But you can put a block in a page which already exist (and so who has a path)

Comment: Does it mean I need to create a new content type, then add one and only entry to that type just to display a single page as a node?

Comment: Best way to do (the simple way) is to create a content type of `basic page` and in **url path setting** put `errors/404`...After go to `admin/config/system/site-information` and follow the procedure

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if properly, you have directory "errors" where have a file 404.html. In Drupal one of the right way to do this is like next: create node Page content type (may by only enter title, see and remember node id after saving), copy node.tpl.php from modules/node folder in your current theme folder, rename this copy to node--NID.tpl.php where NID is id of previosly saved node, then edit this template as you want, then add path alias to this node as "errors/404.html"

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I need. I'll give it a try right now.

Comment: Looks like it was a too simple thing to do, I din't even need to alter the templates, but thanks for advice though.